# What algorithm does Angularjs use to render expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What order of rendering results of executed expressions and way of updating blocks ({{ }}) does Angularjs use ?

Comment: Basically https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js

Answer (score 0):

`{{}}` is nothing but you are adding interpolation directive or you can use `ng-bind` directive for same purpose.

While angular do compile the page it fetches all the directive from the page and do sort them on the basis of priority and Do execute them from higher priority to lower priority.

The directive which are of the same priority, will executed in on the basis of there alphabetical order.

Answer (score -1):

It uses the $digest functionality to do this. Please, lookup $digest and you'll have a better understanding, i feel.